# Java data structure suggestions

Tags: java, data-structures

part of the application am developing is presenting a form to the user and requesting them to either decline it/accept it. There are thee types of users that will need to approve the same form so that it is considered accepted. The suggestion I need is this: What structure can I use/best use to store the user type and their response?
So far I have an object that is Approvers. This holds the three types of users with setters and getters (and other methods related to operations). I also created another object that is UserDecisions where i have two attributes to set, they are: Usertype & response. But I can't think of how to link them together or if there is a better way altogether?
Thanks,

P.s. things i've considered were 2D arrays & hashmaps.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Object model? DB model? Just have a User class, a UserType enum, and a collection of User => Response--a map would be fine; it'd be quicker to look up a user to make sure they don't vote twice.

Comment: object model. nothing to do with database here. Am just asking on how to associate certain replies with users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have

```
User { name, type  }  
         // type is perhaps an enum with values such as administrator,
         // manager, seniorManager, executive 

Response { user, decision }
         // decision is an enum "pending", "approved", "rejected"

Role { name, minimumTypeOfUser }
         // first approval can be done by administrators or above
         // second approval by managers or above
         // third approval by executives only

Approval { Role, Response }


ThingToBeApproved { detalsOfWhatNeedsApproving, approvalList<Approval> }
          // when you set up the approval list you specify each
          // approval role and then select a user whose type matches
          // the role.
```

In systems I work we decouple the Users from the Roles for doing a task - a more senior person on occasion fulfils the junior's role.

Answer (score 1):

A "de-normalized" system would have `User`s, a `UserType` enum (or similar), and a collection of `User` => `Response`s. A map is fine; it speeds up making sure a user doesn't vote twice.

If you need to aggregate answers by `UserType` you could keep a separate tally of `UserType` => `Response`s updated as responses are tallied.

Answer (score 1):

Create a base class for Users. Extend them to create your own customized user class such as Approvers. In UserDecisions Class, create a filed for formName or userName which will link UserDecisions with Users. Or you can create a seperate class for linking purpose.